# Robot Framework - How to get a value inside a list of Rows

Tags: arrays, list, robotframework

I am running a query from robot framework to get an id from the database, The query works but my returned value is `'locationId': ['[('somekindofIdhere', )]` I need to just the `somekindofIdhere` value,

I have tried to get the first index of the list

```
Verify Location Details
     @{Get_LocationId}=  Query  Select locationId From Location WHERE LocationName = '${Name}'
     ${Response_Location}=  Rest.get  http://sampleurl/sample/locations/@{Get_LocationId}[0]
```

but that Gives me back this `('somekindofIdhere', )` how can i get rid of the `()` characters and just get the value?

Comment: The used keyword `Query` is a custom keyword or one from an existing library?

Comment: I am using the DatabaseLibrary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query returns a list of lists - the outer list is a list of rows returned by the query, and the inner lists are lists of columns. This will be true even if the query returns a single column in a single row. You can use robot's embedded variable syntax to reference the value you want:

```
${Response_Location}=  Rest.get  http://sampleurl/sample/locations/${Get_LocationId[0][0]}
```

Here is a complete that that illustrates the difference. I'm simulating the data in `@{Get_LocationId}` so that the test doesn't require an actual database connection.

```
*** Test Cases ***   
Example
    # simulate a list of tuples as returned by a db query    
    ${Get_LocationId}=  evaluate  [('somekindofIdhere',)]

    should be equal as strings  ${Get_LocationId}        [('somekindofIdhere',)]
    should be equal as strings  @{Get_LocationId}[0]     ('somekindofIdhere',)
    should be equal as strings  ${Get_LocationId[0]}     ('somekindofIdhere',)
    should be equal as strings  ${Get_Locationid[0][0]}  somekindofIdhere
```

Comment: I am getting this error now- 'locationId': ["The value '['somekindofIdhere'][0]' is not valid."]}

Comment: @WojtekT: my apologies. I messed up the variable reference. The `[0][0]` needs to be inside the curly braces.

Comment: I have tried that previously and the error i was getting was : `Value of variable '@{Get_LocationId[0][0]}' is not list or list-like.
` I just relized I was using `@` instead of `$` Thanks for the answer, That works